# Jenkins hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm using CentOS 5 and Jenkins 1.430. When I try to build, I get an error:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /home/build/jenkins/workspace/tests at hudson.remoting.Channel@6c89db9a:build-test
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:754)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:705)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:654)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1193)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:454)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1376)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on build-test failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:690)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:747)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.model.Hudson
    at hudson.scm.SubversionWorkspaceSelector.syncWorkspaceFormatFromMaster(SubversionWorkspaceSelector.java:85)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.createSvnClientManager(SubversionSCM.java:782)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:725)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:712)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:1995)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Email was triggered for: Failure
Sending email for trigger: Failure
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

This thread seems to say it's something wrong with Master/Slave:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jenkinsci-issues/MaMqjK3iW8Y

But it doesn't really offer a solution. The Jenkin slave says it's connected and it's reflected on the Jenkins project page.

Comment: How did you connect this slave, ssh? Does the user you connected with have permissions to create those directories?

Comment: I launch it with `javaws <link-to-slave-agent.jnlp>`

Comment: you are launching it with the build user?

Comment: Actually I don't need to launch it like that. In the configure I see that it's already doing an ssh as the build user. But the error still persists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well apparently disabling the slave and rebooting it worked. bleh

Comment: I restarted the Jenkins service on the slave (Windows Server 2008), but did not have to restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to reboot then simply kill these processes on the slave

```
$ ps -ef | grep java
1006     11948 11930  0 Jul17 ?        00:00:00 bash -c cd "/mnt/jenkins" && java  -jar slave.jar
1006     11949 11948  0 Jul17 ?        00:02:55 java -jar slave.jar
```

Then launch the slave agent again

Answer (score 0):

Got a quite similar error, and fixed it by reverting the "publish over ssh" plug-in from 1.14 to 1.13

*Our Jenkins server is run on Debian 8.2 (Jessie), and our slaves under Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)*

Answer (score 0):

Terminated the slave and launched it again. Working perfectly.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you intend to comment, you need to have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).